# Как грамотно вытащить значения из строки?

Tags: c#

Имею следующие строки:

```
Level 1<br/><small style='color:#3498db;'></small>Costs 2 keys, 22 refined<br/>
Level 10<br/><small style='color:#3498db;'></small>Costs 9.66 refined<br/>
Level 1<br/><small style='color:#3498db;'></small>Costs 30 refined<br/>
Level 10<br/><span style='color:#CF6A32'>Strange Part: Critical</span><br/><small style='color:#3498db;'></small>Costs 2 keys, 6.33 refined<br/><span style='color:#16a085;'>3.88 refined off original price of 2 keys, 10.22 refined</span><br/>
```

Помогите достать грамотно значения цены, а именно `Costs 2 keys, 6.33 refined`. Загвоздка вот в чем, данное значение может иметь только `key` либо только `refined`, еще в данной строке может быть информация о скидке (последняя строка `3.88 refined off original price of 2 keys, 10.22 refined`).

В итоге надо получить из 1 строки - 2 значения, `keys` и `refined`.

Мой вариант заключается в методе `Substring`, но как по мне это слишком громоздко и на вид вовсе костылем попахивает...

```
var keyTemp = decimal.Parse(param.Substring(param.IndexOf("Costs") + 6,
                            param.IndexOf("key") - param.IndexOf("Costs") - 7), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Также этот код должен довольно быстро выполнится (хотя с такой строкой я думаю тут любой метод будет работать быстро).

Comment: Каким-нибудь html парсером находим нужный тег, а далее регулярным выражением вытаскиваем нужную информацию.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Не поверите, html парсером вытащил то, что я указал выше. Далее в строках нужные значения не находятся в каких либо тегах и по этому приходится работать именно с таким текстом. По поводу регулярок и спрашиваю, как грамотно это сделать..